# BigDecimal: Issue with zero as last decimal

Tags: spring-boot, type-conversion, bigdecimal

I have a Spring Boot application consuming a rest api delivering some decimal values
for example:

```js
"Amount": {
  "Amount": 160.10,
  "Currency": "EUR"
}
```

I map this to `BigDecimal` which is giving me issues. I need the last decimal, even if it is zero, because I need the amount with no decimals, ie using `BigDecimal.unscaledValue()`

For the shown data I would expect the output of `x.getAmount().unscaledValue()` to be `"16010"` but since the value is internally represented as `160.1` (non-significant 0 is stripped) I get `"1601"` which is a factor of 10 off, when some code further down the line divides by 10.

The value can have either 0, 2 or 3 decimal places (depending on the currency).

My first thought was to use the `setScale()` method, but that brought me no luck.

### Java 11 code to parse json:

```java
restTemplate 
  .exchange(request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<NotificationMessage>>() {})
  .getBody()
```

### model:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategies;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class TransactionAmount {
//  @JsonRawValue //my test to force it
    private BigDecimal amount;

    private String currency;

}
```

Is there a way I can force Spring Boot to preserve the non-significant decimals?

(modifying the API to use strings instead is not an option)

Comment: What should be the outcome in your example? Please make some examples because I don't understand your question

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have added an example

Comment: I udnerstand but what would you expect for 160.100

Comment: I'd expect `"160100"` and for `160` I'd expect `"160"`

Comment: That's exactly how it works. But how do you create the BigDecimal?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simply to introduce a custom `Jackson` `Mapper` which parses the value as `String` instead of `float`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategies;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;
import lombok.Data;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class TransactionAmount {

    private BigDecimal amt;

    private String ccy;
    
    // Custom mapper to make sure we get the complete decimal value - by treating the amount as a String instead of a Float
    @JsonCreator
    public TransactionAmount1(
      @JsonProperty("Amt") String amount, 
      @JsonProperty("Ccy") String ccy) {
        this.amt = new BigDecimal(amount);
        this.ccy = ccy;
    }

}
```